# afterEach Jest not clearing my totalScore

Tags: javascript, jestjs

For some reason I am getting:

1st test passes:
"Love all"

2nd test fails:
Expected: "Fifteen love"
Received: "Fifteen loveLove all"

As I understand it, I need to be using afterEach to tear down the original configuration. I have tried this but it doesn't seem to 'wipe' the totalScore.

Thanks  for your help!

**Test file:**

```
  const Tennis = require("../src/index");

describe("Tennis game", () => {
  let tennis;
  beforeEach(() => {
    tennis = new Tennis();
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    tennis.resetGame();
  });

  const scoreShouldBe = (expected) => {
    tennis.getScore();
    expect(tennis.totalScore).toBe(expected);
  };

  test("Love all", () => {
    scoreShouldBe("Love all");
  });

  test("Fifteen love", () => {
    tennis.firstPlayerScore();
    scoreShouldBe("Fifteen love");
  });
});
```

**Index.js file:**

```
    class Tennis {
  constructor() {
    this.firstPlayerScoreTimes = 0;
    this.totalScore = "";
  }
  getScore() {
    if (this.firstPlayerScoreTimes === 1) {
      this.totalScore += "Fifteen love";
    }
    this.totalScore += "Love all";
  }

  firstPlayerScore() {
    this.firstPlayerScoreTimes++;
  }

  resetGame() {
    this.totalScore = "";
  }
}

module.exports = Tennis;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test is working well, what you need to update is your production code.

Current logic, when `firstPlayerScoreTimes` is 1, you set the score as `Fifteen love` and also append `Love all` string to the score. I guess this is not your requirement. Let's update the `getScore` function:

```
  getScore() {
    if (this.firstPlayerScoreTimes === 1) {
      return this.totalScore += "Fifteen love"; // stop, that's enough 
    }
    this.totalScore += "Love all";
  }
```

Comment: Thank you SO much hoangdv!! Literally was just missing a 'return'. That has really helped my understanding, thank you for taking the time to look at this. Have a great day :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove `+=` in your `getScore` method in the `Tennis` class as it will add the new string to the old string.

```
class Tennis {
  constructor() {
    this.firstPlayerScoreTimes = 0;
    this.totalScore = "";
  }
  getScore() {
    if (this.firstPlayerScoreTimes === 1) {
      this.totalScore = "Fifteen love";
    }
    this.totalScore = "Love all";
  }

  firstPlayerScore() {
    this.firstPlayerScoreTimes++;
  }

  resetGame() {
    this.totalScore = "";
  }
}

module.exports = Tennis;
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the reply. Initially I wondered if this might solve it, when running the above I then get the 2nd test still failing, this time:

Expected: "Fifteen love"
    Received: "Love all"

Comment: I geuss you also have to change your `beforeEach`, as it updates the `tennis` instance, but that is not needed. There are multiple tennis instances currently and that can also cause some weird behavior. Update to `const tennis = new Tennis();` should be enough.